# intro level set theory question.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $X\cap(Y\cup Z) = (X\cap Y) \cup Z \ \iff Z\subseteq X$

I think I have figured out one direction:

Assume $Z\subseteq X$ then $Z\cap X= Z$. We know $X\cap(Y\cup Z)=(X\cap Y)\cup (X\cap Z)$. So $X\cap(Y\cup Z)=(X\cap Y) \cup Z.$

I am having trouble with the other direction. I was to assume $X\cap(Y\cup Z) = (X\cap Y) \cup Z$ and show $Z\subseteq X.$ How do I go about this? I have tried using the "distributive" property a bunch, but I get lost... What is the best way to go about something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $Z\subseteq\left(X\cap Y\right)\cup Z$ so that $X\cap\left(Y\cup Z\right)=\left(X\cap Y\right)\cup Z$
implies that $Z\subseteq X\cap\left(Y\cup Z\right)\subseteq X$.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to prove the contrapositive of that implication. Start by assuming that $Z$ is not contained in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof:** If there is $x \in Z\setminus X$, then

$x\notin X\cap (Y \cup Z)$, however, $x\in (X\cap Y) \cup Z$. A tradiction!